# Pushing to remote repository from IDEA doesn't work

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-push, github-for-windows

As a newbie, I chose to use GitHub for Windows version from the official site. I have added the path to git executable in IntelliJ IDEA settings.

Using graphical interface, I have cloned a project from remote github repo. Now, when I make some changes into project files and press PUSH button, only commit to my local version happens. All screens concerning choosing files to commit appear, except the final menu that should ask for my github credentials doesn't appear at all. No errors or warning are displayed

When I open the GitHub UI, I can see the last unsynchronized commit and I am able to synchronize it using the synchronize button or by opening the github shell and typing
              `git push origin master`

Maybe I am lacking the general understanding how git should work. Any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE:

Here is the complete log of my last attempt to commit to remote repo:

```
20:35:21.996: cd C:\NetCracker\ProjectVersions\GitHubClone_16_11_2013\NCLodger
20:35:21.996: git log origin/master..master --name-status --pretty=format:%x01%h%x02%H%x02  %ct%x02%an%x02%at%x02%ae%x02%cn%x02%ce%x02%p%x02%d%x02%s%x02%b%x02%B%x03 --encoding=UTF-8 -- .
20:37:00.397: cd C:\NetCracker\ProjectVersions\GitHubClone_16_11_2013\NCLodger
20:37:00.397: git config core.autocrlf
true
20:37:00.544: cd C:\NetCracker\ProjectVersions\GitHubClone_16_11_2013\NCLodger
20:37:00.544: git commit --only -F C:\Users\Ferbolg\AppData\Local\Temp\git-commit-msg-2050500670215297705.txt -- src/main/webapp/smsettings.jsp
[master da7c7fe] User dashboard link removed from sales manager page (For testing git work only)
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

20:37:00.782: cd C:\NetCracker\ProjectVersions\GitHubClone_16_11_2013\NCLodger
20:37:00.782: git log origin/master..master --name-status --pretty=format:%x01%h%x02%H%x02%ct%x02%an%x02%at%x02%ae%x02%cn%x02%ce%x02%p%x02%d%x02%s%x02%b%x02%B%x03 --encoding=UTF-8 -- .
20:37:06.545: git push origin master:master
```

Comment: What does the console say?  Are you sure that your local branch is set up to track the remote branch?

Comment: I am not sure. Could you please provide a tip where I can check it ?

Comment: Enter `git remote -v` to see if you have any remote repositories set up.

Comment: When I enter this command in PowerShell, it returns me `origin  https://github.com/reshet/NCLodger.git` for `fetch` and `push`. And `git remote show origin`returns me in the end `Local ref configured for 'git push': master pushes to master (local out of date)` Maybe the problem is in the last ?